# how to share class between c++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My VS2012 Solution contains several VC++ projects.
I also have many common files that need to be shared.
It's easy to share enum's and structures. I just "include" corresponding header file and that's it. I even don't need to compile my "commons" project!

But what if I need to share more complex classes that contain both .h and .cpp files, and so need to be compiled?

And the most complicated question - can I share thread-safe singleton? I want to access it from different projects from different threads (but from one process).

I guess I should use something like static or dynamic linking, but i'm not sure. Probably someone can link step-by-step tutorial to solve such problem?

I would prefer something portable as I will move entire solution to Linux later.

Comment: What about a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects that contain classes that you want to share should export their symbols.  When you create a DLL project in Visual Studio you can give it the option to "Export" symbols and it provides some boiler-plate code for you to use.

In essence, in your libraries header file, it will give you:

```
// myapi.h

#if defined(MYAPIEXPORTS)
    #define MYAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MYAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

'MYAPIEXPORTS' is provided by the wizard, but it's a compiler preprocessor directive ONLY on the library itself.  Hence when you compile the library, `MYAPI` is for exporting and when the header file is included in your other projects, it will be for importing.

Now let's look at a class you want to share.

```
// myclass.h

class MYAPI MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};


// myclass.cpp
#include "myClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() { /* ... */ };
MyClass::~MyClass() { /* .... */ }
```

Your other projects then need to link with the resulting .lib file that is generated.

Note that if you have a `template<>` class contained entirely within a header file, you do not export it.  That will behave like your enums and typedefs.

To answer the second part of your question, yes a singleton defined in your library will be accessible to the main project also.

Comment: thanks I've used this tutorial and it's fine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @javapowered, glad you found that.  Note that the tutorial you linked is for static functions only, and not exporting classes you may wish to create instances of.